# How to search in list

Tags: python, search

Getting a list from mongodb and sorting it:

```
results = list(db1.zaklad.find({"name": "cola", "stav": '+'}))
print(a)
sorted_results = sorted(results, key=itemgetter('weight'), reverse=True)
```

Im getting: `[{'_id': ObjectId('5a13a8c396fb3488bb6a0648'), 'name': 'cola', 'weight': '3', 'url': 'goo.gl/2BgLmm', 'stav': '+', 'time_exp': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 23, 37, 31, 946000)}, {'_id': ObjectId('5a13a8bc96fb3488bb6a0647'), 'name': 'cola', 'weight': '2', 'url': 'goo.gl/2BgLmm', 'stav': '+', 'time_exp': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 23, 37, 31, 946000)}, {'_id': ObjectId('5a13a8ca96fb3488bb6a0649'), 'name': 'cola', 'weight': '2', 'url': 'goo.gl/2BgLmm', 'stav': '+', 'time_exp': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 23, 37, 31, 946000)}`

From this list I want to get all un-repeating weights(from example above: `3, 2`).

So, how to search in this list?
Or its better to do dictionary with `dict(enumerate(results))`?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

If list is already sorted, create a new list, put the first weight of `sorted_results` in it, remember the weight of this item and iterate over the remaining items:

If an item has same weight as remembered weight, ignore it, if it has another weight, add it to the new list and remember the new weight instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

get weights

```
weights = [dic["weight"] for dic in results]
```

remove duplicates by converting to set

```
set(weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by un-repeating weight value from results.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_results = OrderedDict({k['weight']:k for k in sorted(results, key=lambda x:x['weight'], reverse=True)})
```

You can get an ordered results:

```
OrderedDict([('3', {'stav': '+', 'name': 'cola', 'weight': '3', 'url': 'goo.gl/2BgLmm', 'time_exp': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 23, 37, 31, 946000), '_id': ObjectId('5a13a8c396fb3488bb6a0648')}), ('2', {'stav': '+', 'name': 'cola', 'weight': '2', 'url': 'goo.gl/2BgLmm', 'time_exp': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 23, 37, 31, 946000), '_id': ObjectId('5a13a8ca96fb3488bb6a0649')})])
```

You can get the value with 'weight' value '3' by using ordered_result['3']